# Backgrounds location of MS Teams PWA on Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-teams, progressive-web-app

When using the Windows client of Microsoft Teams it is possible to navigate to the respective AppData folder where backgrounds for your live stream are stored and manually dump an animated gif with the .jpeg extension there, thus bypassing the sanity checks of the built in upload mechanism.

I am wondering whether there is a similar workaround for the PWA based Teams client that Linux users are forced to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there's no solution for PWA on Linux at the moment.
The PWA is just doing what the web version is providing,
which doesn't include custom backgrounds.
See the post at:
[Upload custom background using web or PWA on Linux](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/upload-custom-background-using-web-or-pwa-on-linux/331951b0-3c8a-457a-8fd5-58157e5fc765?page=1).

You could try the
[ms-teams-replace-background](https://gitlab.com/parrot_parrot/ms-teams-replace-background),
described as:

> The goal is to create a background replacer for MS Teams and similar video conferencing tools, since this feature is not usually not available on Linux. This code manipulates the video stream from webcam before it is streamed into video conferencing software, such that participant in the chat can not see the backgound behind the person.

---

Otherwise, you would need to use a Windows client, on a
virtual machine or perhaps on Wine.

For Windows, according to the the MS Teams post
[Custom Background In MS Teams](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/custom-background-in-ms-teams/m-p/1286079),
the backgrounds folder of Teams is:
`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads`.

The sub-folders of `Backgrounds\Uploads` may be missing in
`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams` and may need to be created.

Comment: This is true for a Windows native client. I am looking for a solution for a Linux progressiv web app client, however.

Comment: I added more to my answer.